# What permissions are required to view the contents of a catalog on a remote server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I defined a linked server from a SQL Server box to a MySQL box.  I went through a very detailed set of instructions and steps, everything works like a charm when I am logged in.

The linked server definition specifies a MySQL account to access the MySQL database (all connections).

When I use my own (administrator) account to login, the links works great.  I can both query the tables and view a list of tables in the remote catalog.

When I login with a read-only account, I can run queries against the link, but am unable to view a list of tables (in SSMS).

What extra permission do I need to grant to this read-only SQL login in order to get it to fully work?

**Update**
I found a work-around:

```
exec sp_Tables_ex 'LinkesServername'
```

Works good enough.

Comment: I would not have added the mysql tag, because the issue is not at the mysql end.  The same login is being used (as defined in the linked server definition) regardless of what SQL Server account is currently logged in.